# Why is my suitescript form parameter null?

Tags: javascript, netsuite

I have a script. I have linked the script to "Custom Code" on the "Custom Transaction Form" for Opportunity.

I am trying to call my function onload

```
function customizeSublistButtons(type, form, request){
    var list = form.getSubList("Items");
```

However form is always undefined. Am I missing a step

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you are mixing and matching your event handlers. Linking the script on the "Custom Code" tab of a form effectively creates a *Client Script*. The event akin to `onload` in a Client Script is `Page Init`. The `Page Init` event handler does not get passed any parameters, so your `form` parameter is always going to be `null`.

It looks like you are trying to use the parameter signature for a *User Event's* `Before Load` function.

To see the difference, check out the NetSuite Help pages titled:

- "Client Event Types"
- "User Event Script Execution Types"

These pages will describe the details of each possible event handler function, including the parameters they get passed. You will want to reference the `Page Init` definition on the Client Script page and build your function accordingly.

Comment: OK - I created a new User Event Script. Attached my script and put my function in "BEFORE LOAD FUNCTION". I then created a deployment script for Opportunity. I select Create Opportunity and nothing is called. Did I miss something?

Comment: That all sounds right; can you reply with your function declaration and also exactly what you are entering in the Before Load Function field?

Comment: I started from scratch this time. And the user event does now fire with the parameters passed thank you.